# What simple set theory topics do you find interesting?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, set-theory

I'm currently in my final year of a math undergrad degree and need to start writing my senior capstone. I've recently gotten very interested in the concept of set theory and have read through some information online and most recently I finished Halmos's Naive Set Theory. I was speaking to my advisor about the possibility of writing a set theoretic definition of the real numbers, but he seems concerned that giving a thorough explanation will be too long.

My capstone prompt is incredibly broad:  write at least 10 pages about something to do with math. I'm overwhelmed by the possibilities and feel like everything I come across would take 20-30 pages minimum to describe. Although it's not a specific math solution I'm looking for, I was wondering if anyone has any relatively simple concepts that they find interesting or even a book/article suggestion so I have somewhere to start?

Thank you in advance! I'm excited about the field and doing the research, just overwhelmed with options.

Comment: Have you considered discussing large cardinals and/or proper classes, perhaps even the relation between large cardinals and the axiom of choice (or with ZFC more specifically)? Also, does this include category theory, have you learned much about that?

Comment: This question is very opinion-based, so I'm voting to close it. Consider editing to a question that can be answered based on facts.

Comment: Transfinite recursion has some fun uses to it.